# About setting up the local repository Hortonworks

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to learn setting up local repository using Hortonworks Ambair (for HDP).

**I am referring to the official guide of Hortonworks; refer below:**

[image]

I am not able to understand why do we have to download .repo file and the .tar file?

Is .repo file required in case when we have temporary access and some process would download the actual binaries? If so, then which process downloads this?

Is .tar.gz file required in case we don't have any internet access at all, and this .tar.gz refers to actual software distribution?

Can anyone guide me what is the meaning of these?

Answer (score 1):

The .repo file is a configuration file used by yum to download binaries from a remote centralized server.

The .tar file is a compressed file of all those binaries which you can install on your local network and serve them (via httpd or the like) to all the nodes of the cluster that are on that same local network.

If you have temporary internet access you could use the .repo file to download and/or install the binaries. If you only want to download the binaries you'd do something like:

```
# yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
# yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>
```

If you wanted to download and install you would simply:

```
# yum install <package>
```

If you don't have any internet access you would need to download the .tar file on a computer that does have internet access and transfer it to your cluster and follow the [instructions](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_setting_up_a_local_repository_with_no_internet_access.html) provided by Hortonworks on setting up a locally served repository.